When reporting roll attitude, is that relative to the horizon or relative to the Earth frame?
I'm trying to figure out if what I've always thought of as roll from the cockpit is not in fact roll at all.
The Tait-Bryan convention defines RPY (roll, pitch, and yaw) as the Euler angles from the Earth-fixed coordinate system. However, when I'm in the cockpit, looking at a gyroscope, I'm seeing my wings relative to the horizon. This is what I have imagined the attitude indicator indicates.
At 0 degrees of pitch, Euler and gyroscope correspond perfectly, but they diverge as pitch gets farther from 0. It's not a huge difference, though; for instance an Euler pitch angle of 40 degrees and an Euler roll angle of 60 degrees leads to a 53 degree angle made between the wings and the horizon.
(For the mathematics of why, this has to do with the difference between rotations about a body-frame axis and rotations about the world-frame. While the gyroscope is reporting the difference between the horizon and the wings, the Euler angles are defined about the world-frame. The above discrepancy can be confirmed by looking at the horizontal basis vectors of the {1,2,3} sequence where theta = 40 and phi = 60. When examining the body coordinate frame's y-axis the divergence is clear.)
So when I talk about roll as a pilot, which am I actually talking about? I'm assuming roll relative to the horizon, but I'm really not sure anymore. I realize it doesn't particularly matter, since if you're 40 degrees nose down and at 60 degrees of bank, the 7 degree difference isn't really your critical problem at that moment... But I am curious as to which I should use when reporting RPY values from an autopilot.

Excellent question, perhaps a dup of What are the exact meanings of roll, pitch and yaw? (you decide). See also bank vs roll angles.

@mins thatnks for those links. I think quiet flyer's discussion of attitude, and its various slippery definitions, helps. I don't think it quite clears up the confusion yet. (Part of that is because I don't see much consensus around his claims, although I think they do make a lot of sense.) I feel like there must be a reference source which specifically addresses the two, and gives mathematical conversions between the pilot perspective and the inertial frame perspective. Maybe the pilot is just technically wrong in calling it "roll", but the error is tiny so .

Not visalizing the question yet; at (say) 40 degrees of pitch, 0 roll is the same in either frame, but 60 degrees of roll differs; what about 90 degrees of roll - is that case different between the two frames of reference?

Correct. And at 90 degrees of roll, the discrepancy returns to 0. There's a maximum somewhere near, but exactly at, where Euler angle roll and pitch are the same.

When you say "reporting" and "talking about it" as a pilot, what do you actually mean?  Because while I broadly understand the nuances, it has never been an issue worth mentioning, even in briefing and debriefing dynamic aerobatic and combat maneuvers, much less an autopilot.  Also, consider 90 degrees nose up or down - you can still roll the airplane but what is the frame of reference then?

@MichaelHall I don't understand your question. It might never have been an issue worth mentioning, but it's still a divergence in the notation of the flight dynamics vs the cockpit view. I wish to understand this better.

I'm just trying to clarify whether by "reporting" you mean communicating detailed autopilot numerical software data, and "talking about it" means discussing with engineers how to make the autopilot work properly WRT this data.  I assure you I am not trying to be pedantic or petty, just trying to put this query in context.  Because at small pitch angles aren't the frames of reference close enough to not matter?

@MichaelHall, by reporting, I mean if I'm in the cockpit, I look at my attitude indicator, and say, e.g., "I'm at 10 degrees of pitch and 20 degrees of roll." In that case, I am reporting the roll attitude as the angle that the airplane silhouette's wings make with the horizon, and the pitch as the bar the silhouette's nose is touching.

Hmmm, I'm guessing on most relevant flight instruments (or HUDs), if you're 60 deg or more nose-down, the artificial horizon is not within view anyway.

Ok, I won't belabor this any more, but at the risk of sounding flippant, do you actually voice the words "I'm at 10 degrees of pitch and 20 degrees of roll"? If so, to whom, and for what reason?! My point is that when you "talk about roll as a pilot" the sort of distinctions you are asking about are largely irrelevant unless you are involved in flight test or engineering. It's an intelligent question, (I think...) but the way you've framed the issue is puzzling because there's no clear problem statement or practical reason for ordinary pilots to really care about or use such terminology.


However, when I'm in the cockpit, looking at a gyroscope, I'm seeing my wings relative to the horizon. This is what I have imagined the attitude indicator indicates.

It is correct. The Earth-Fixed frame is partially constructed by the AI: The AI gyroscope maintains its rotation in a local horizontal plane, about its vertical axis, and therefore can sense a change in both in pitch and roll independently as seen on this diagram:

Source.
When the aircraft pitch angle changes, the gyro rotates the orange gimbal about the horizontal pitch axis (actually the gimbal is fixed, the rest rotates). The pink roll gimbal doesn't move, but the pink pin (which should be orange, I guess) moves up or down when rotating with the orange gimbal using the aperture in the gimbal. This moves the arm and the dial up or down (but doesn't change the roll angle).
When the aircraft roll angle changes, the gyro rotates the pink roll gimbal, and the dial with it.

an Euler pitch angle of 40 degrees and an Euler roll angle of 60 degrees leads to a 53 degree angle made between the wings and the horizon.

Let use this body-fixed frame, a right-handed one common in aerospace:

Source: Introduction to Aeronautics
The standard chain of rotation is an intrinsic z-y-x on the body frame (the 3-2-1 Tait-Bryan convention) for yaw, pitch and roll in this order. In this convention the final orientation of the body, is obtained this way:

The body frame is initially aligned with the Earth frame.

The body frame is rotated about its z-axis (vertical axis) by the yaw angle ($\Psi$). This changes the orientation of the other axes of the body frame, let's call the new orientations x' and y'.
The corresponding transformation matrix is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos \Psi & \sin \Psi & 0 \\
  -\sin \Psi & \cos \Psi & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$$

The body frame is rotated about y'-axis by the pitch angle ($\theta$). This changes the orientation of the other axes, let's call the new axes x" and z". The rotation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos \theta & 0 & -\sin \theta \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  \sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta
  \end{bmatrix}$$

The body frame is rotated about the x"-axis by the roll angle ($\Phi$). The rotation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & \cos \Phi & \sin \Phi \\
  0 & -\sin \Phi & \cos \Phi
  \end{bmatrix}$$




In this situation the body frame as been rolled by the roll angle, whatever the previous yaw and pitch rotations. For example if yaw and pitch are 0°, the body frame would still be rolled by the same angle. This shows the roll angle is always the angle between the y-axis (y') of the body frame and its projection on the horizontal plane (xy plane of the Earth frame) so:

When reporting roll attitude, is that relative to the horizon or relative to the Earth frame?

Relative to both, as these two concepts are coincident.
Transformation matrices
Let select the Earth frame to be a flat-Earth NED, and the rotations yaw ($\Psi$), pitch ($\theta$), roll ($\Phi$) associated with a 321 Tait-Bryan order like above. The two transformation matrices are indeed the simple composition of the individual rotations and it inverse:
For NED to body-fixed:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c \theta c \Psi & 
c \theta s \Psi & 
-s \theta \\
s \Phi s \theta c \Psi - c \Phi s \Psi & 
s \Phi s \theta s \Psi + c \Phi c \Psi & 
s \Phi c \theta \\
c \Phi s \theta c \Psi + s \Phi s \Psi & 
c \Phi s \theta s \Psi - s \Phi c \Psi & 
c \Phi c \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and for body-fixed to NED (in this case the inverse is the transpose):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c \theta c \Psi & 
s \Phi s \theta c \Psi - c \Phi s \Psi & 
c \Phi s \theta c \Psi + s \Phi s \Psi \\
c \Phi s \Psi & 
s \Phi s \theta s \Psi + c \Phi c \Psi & 
c \Phi s \theta s \Psi - s \Phi c \Psi \\
-s \theta & 
s \Phi c \theta & 
c \Phi c \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Were c means cosine and s means sine. I copied the matrices from USAF Equations of motion which also provides a formal explanation in §13.4.1, similar to my answer. It may be easier to follow.
Euler vs Tait-Bryan
Euler formulated a method to describe any 3D solid angle by a sequence of 3 rotations over the 2 axes. So the first and last rotations use the same axis (with two cases for the last rotation, original or rotated axis). Tait-Bryan is another method where the 3 different axes are used once. Tait-Bryan compositions are more simple when describing the aircraft attitude.
See Methods of Representing Solid Angles for more details.

I need some time to go through the rest, but the projection onto the WCS yz-plane of the line made by the 2nd basis vector of the body-fixed coordinates as seen from the WCS is not parallel to a line on the yz-plane tilted by the euler angle roll value. (I know that's a word salad, sorry!) Formulating a rotation matrix with 0 yaw and looking at the second row makes this apparent.

It is, though, important to note that the WCS as seen from the body frame is represented by the column vectors of the rotation matrix. This is perhaps precisely what the AI is indicating, which is how the pilot sees the world, and not how the world sees the pilot.
